# Powershell - use string from function in Outfile

Tags: powershell

I'am trying to use the return string from the function as file name for the downloaded file as timestamp. I'm not shure, why is does not work. Can you help me please?

Thank you!

```
    Push-Location $(Split-Path $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
Invoke-WebRequest https://chartership.eu/images/preislisten/CS-Preis-Belegung.xlsx.pdf -Outfile Get-TimeStamp

function Get-TimeStamp {

    return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}].pdf" -f (Get-Date)

}
```

Comment: If you problem has been answered satisfactorily, please mark it as the answer.  If not, please comment on what you still are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't allow `:` in the filename.  Additionally, PowerShell really doesn't like `[` or `]` in folder or filenames, either.  I really just changed the format string and added parenthesis around `Get-TimeStamp` so it would call the function instead of using that as the filename.

This worked for me:

```
function Get-TimeStamp {
    "{0:MM-dd-yy} {0:HH_mm_ss}.pdf" -f (Get-Date)
}

Push-Location $(Split-Path $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)

Invoke-WebRequest  https://chartership.eu/images/preislisten/CS-Preis-Belegung.xlsx.pdf -Outfile (Get-TimeStamp)
```

Comment: You can simplify with `"{0:MM-dd-yy HH_mm_ss}.pdf" -f (Get-Date)`

Comment: Indeed you can.  I was just working with what was provided.